# Was Princess Diana murdered?

Tags: criminology, celebrities

Was there foul play involved with the fatal car crash that [killed Princess Diana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Diana,_Princess_of_Wales)?

It seems that the best conclusion was that their BMW was speeding on that night to try and escape from aggressive paparazzi.

Comment: It was a Mercedes-Benz, not a BMW.